# parent ids sometimes empty

Tags: cart

I would like to access some attributes of a simple products parent. By this I mean: I have a configurable product with an additional manufacturer property. The configurable product can be configured by a size attribute. In the catalogue one can only see the configurable products, **BUT** on the cart view this is different. I would like to display the manufacturer, but since the product is a child product, the value of

```
$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

is just an empty string.

So I load the parent product, using this code:

```
$parentIds   = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                       ->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getID());

$parent      = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);
```

**THE ONLY PROBLEM** I have is that `$parentIds` is sometimes an empty array, even if the product is a child of a configurable one.

When does this come to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access some custom attribute on the cart page you need to instruct Magento to include that particular attribute in the quote item representation of the product.

You can do that in `config.xml` of a custom module by adding following code under `<global>` node:

```
<sales>
    <quote>
        <item>
            <product_attributes>
                <manufacturer/>
            </product_attributes>
        </item>
    </quote>
</sales>
```

You should now be able to get the attribute directly from quote item without product load.
**Note**: `$_item` is instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`

```
$_item->getProduct()->getManufacturer();
```

Or like this, depending on the attribute type:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

Comment: Nice! Works! The `XML + $_item = $this->getProduct();` did it! Is that documented somewhere? Can you provide a link? Cheers!